# Asp.net MVC Validating Dynamic Form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC application with a form that needs validation.  The majority of the form is static, but part of the form is dynamic.

I need to enable the user to enter n string/date combinations.

The string/date combos need to be validated server side, and I need to give feedback to the user preferably directly beside the combination that failed validation.

For static input I do the following:

```
   <%= Html.ValidationMessage("someField") %>
```

For the dynamic data, what should I do?

Comment: Is the dynamic part of the form generated client side or server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller you'll want to assign an error to the particular fields that fail validation:

```
ModelState.AddModelError ("textbox1", "You must specify a valid string.");
ModelState.AddModelError ("combobox1", "You must specify a valid date.");
```

Then all the helper is really doing is checking if the following exists:

```
ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey("textbox1")
```

and then creating a tag such as follows

```
<span><%= ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey("textbox1").Errors[0] %></span>
```

the helper does a bit more null value checking but you get the idea.